# Display unicode characters in a JLabel on OS X

Tags: java, swing, unicode

For [JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/), we have a LaTeX to Unicode converter to display e.g. italic fonts in titles. On my Mac however, this is not rendered correctly although I see the correct Unicode string inside the debugger ([issue on GitHub](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/3356)). I'm attaching a minimal example using the created Unicode string. What I see on my machine (MacOS Sierra 10.12.6, Java 1.8.0_144) is the following

[image: img]

while the debugger in IDEA correctly shows

[image: img2]

Is there someone who can share some insight how this can be resolved? I read through several SO posts that suggested to use a font that supports this or setting font size in a certain way. However, I'm not adjusting any of this here. Why does this fail in the default settings?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SwingJLabelTester extends JPanel{

    private SwingJLabelTester() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,1));
//        final String latexString = LatexToUnicodeAdapter.format("This is a \\textit{test for italics} and \\textbf{a test for bold}");
        final String latexString = "This is a \uD835\uDC61\uD835\uDC52\uD835\uDC60\uD835\uDC61 \uD835\uDC53\uD835\uDC5C\uD835\uDC5F \uD835\uDC56\uD835\uDC61\uD835\uDC4E\uD835\uDC59\uD835\uDC56\uD835\uDC50\uD835\uDC60 and \uD835\uDC1A \uD835\uDC2D\uD835\uDC1E\uD835\uDC2C\uD835\uDC2D \uD835\uDC1F\uD835\uDC28\uD835\uDC2B \uD835\uDC1B\uD835\uDC28\uD835\uDC25\uD835\uDC1D";
        final JLabel label = new JLabel(latexString, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(label);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("LabelDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SwingJLabelTester());
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SwingJLabelTester::createAndShowGUI);
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the font properties in the Java installation. It affects JavaFX too. A workaround is specifying fonts; e.g., `final String latexString = "<html><body>This is a <font face='STIXGeneral'>\uD835\uDC61\uD835\uDC52\uD835\uDC60\uD835\uDC61 \uD835\uDC53\uD835\uDC5C\uD835\uDC5F \uD835\uDC56\uD835\uDC61\uD835\uDC4E\uD835\uDC59\uD835\uDC56\uD835\uDC50\uD835\uDC60</font> and <font face='STIXGeneral'>\uD835\uDC1A \uD835\uDC2D\uD835\uDC1E\uD835\uDC2C\uD835\uDC2D \uD835\uDC1F\uD835\uDC28\uD835\uDC2B \uD835\uDC1B\uD835\uDC28\uD835\uDC25\uD835\uDC1D</font></body></html>";`

Comment: @VGR Nice. I could verify the missing glyphs by extracting the font from the label and using `font.canDisplay(c)` for all chars. None of the Unicode chars can be displayed. I iterated through all fonts on my system and apparently, no font can display these chars. Would you agree that using simple html instead of Unicode chars is a better option?

Comment: **Yes.**  I thought those characters were just your example of supplementary characters.  If your goal is simply to show bold and/or italic text, you should *never* use the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block of Unicode to accomplish that.  That Unicode block has a specific purpose, related to mathemtical formulae;  any other use is abuse of the characters.  You don’t even need fonts;  just use `"<html><body>This is a <i>test for italics</i> and <b>a test for bold</b></body></html>"`.  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342024/.